# Can PHP handle drag/drop/positioning interactivity?

Tags: php

I'm deciding whether PHP is the best (easiest and most powerful) choice for this task. I have a list of shapes in a panel and would like to drag instances of them into a board as needed. It's not just a drag and drop operation: once the shape is on the board, I still need to be able to reposition and resize it. Also the shapes may be interactive, meaning when I click on the circle for example, it should do something, but each circle is unique, so it's really an instance of the circle (kind of like OOP).

I use PHP, but my gut feeling tells me it may not be the best language to handle this. I'm not sure because I never needed to do something like this before, so maybe PHP could do it after all. I'd like to hear feedback from those more experienced with PHP and other languages. How could I get this done in PHP? If not, what languages would win at doing this hands down.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PHP is server-side, so is unlikely to be useful to effect drag and drop functionality. If you could couple it with JavaScript (or a particular library) and/or html5 it's more likely to work efficiently.

[Remy Sharp](http://www.remysharp.com)'s demo page for html5 drag and drop: http://html5demos.com/drag

Answer (score 3):

PHP is server-side language. Dragging, dropping, positioning and resizing are client-side things and can be handled with JavaScript.